# Removing stop words and saving the new file Perl

Tags: regex, perl, split, stop-words

I have created a Perl file to load in an array of "Stop words".

Then I load in a directory with ".ner" files contained in it.
Each file gets opened and each word is split and compared to the words in the stop file.
If the word matches the word it is changed to "" (nothing-and gets removed)
I then copy the file to another location.  So I can differentiate between files with stop words and files without.
But does this change the file to now contain no stop words or will it revert back to the original?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
#use warnings;

my @stops;
my @file;

use File::Copy;

open( STOPWORD, "/Users/jen/stopWordList.txt" ) or die "Can't Open: $!\n";

@stops = <STOPWORD>;
while (<STOPWORD>)    #read each line into $_
{
    chomp @stops;     # Remove newline from $_
    push @stops, $_;  # add the line to @triggers
}

close STOPWORD;

$dirtoget="/Users/jen/temp/";

opendir(IMD, $dirtoget) || die("Cannot open directory");

@thefiles= readdir(IMD);

foreach $f (@thefiles){
    if ($f =~ m/\.ner$/){
        print $f,"\n";

        open (FILE, "/Users/jen/temp/$f")or die"Cannot open FILE"; 

        if ( FILE eq "" ) {
            close FILE;
        }
        else{
            while (<FILE>) {

               foreach $word(split(/\|/)){

                    foreach $x (@stops) {
                       if  ($x =~ m/\b\Q$word\E\b/) {
                            $word = '';   
             copy("/Users/jen/temp/$f","/Users/jen/correct/$f")or die "Copy failed: $!";
                    close FILE;
                    } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
closedir(IMD);
exit 0;
```

The format of the file I am splitting and comparing is as follows:

```
'<title>|NN|O Woman|NNP|O jumped|VBD|O for|IN|O life|NN|O after|IN|O firebomb|NN|O attack|NN|O -|:|O National|NNP|I-ORG News|NNP|I-ORG ,|,|I-ORG Frontpage|NNP|I-ORG -|:|I-ORG Independent.ie</title>|NNP|'
```

Should I be outlining where the words should be split ie: split(/|/)?

Comment: Does this code even compile? It seems to miss some closing brackets. Can you please add full code and specify a bit better what your problem is? At the moment it does not seem that changed content is written anywhere.

Comment: @Superfilin The full code is above sorry about the formatting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jenniem001,

```
open FILE, ("<$fh")||die("cant");undef $/;my $whole_file = <FILE>;foreach my $word (@words){$whole_file=~s/\b\Q$word\E\b//ig;}open FILE (">>$duplicate")||die("cant");print FILE $whole_file;
```

That will remove stops from your file and create a duplicate. Just call give $duplicate a name :)

Answer (score 2):

You should ALWAYS use :
use strict;
use warnings;

use three args open and test opening for failure.

As said codaddict `A split with no arguments is equivalent to split(' ', $_).`

Here is a proposal to achieve the job (as far as I well understood what you wanted).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my @stops = qw(put here your stop words);
my %stops = map{$_ => 1} @stops;

my @thefiles;

my $path = '/Users/jen/temp/';
my $out = $path.'outputfile';
open my $fout, '>', $out or die "can't open '$out' for writing : $!";

foreach my $file(@thefiles) {
    next unless $file =~ /\.ner$/;
    open my $fh, '<', $path.$file or die "can't open '$file' for reading : $!";
    my @lines = <$file>;
    close $fh;
    foreach my $line(@lines) {
        my @words = split/\|/,$line;
        foreach my $word(@words) {
            $word = '' if exists $stops{$word};
        }
        print $fout join '|',@words;
    }
}
close $out;
```

Comment: I have 
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;` 
In my code I just did not think it would be relevant to put it in my Question.

Answer (score 1):

A `split` with no arguments is equivalent to `split(' ', $_)`.

Since you want the lines to be split on `|` you need to do:

```
split/\|/
```

Comment: What about writing in to a new file? Or appending the file I think at the moment I am just copying the original file to another folder but I want to copy the file minus the stop words to the new folder.?!